# How do I reject all inputs that are NOT integers?

Tags: python

I need help to solve the following problem:
Expected output:

> Please input an integer: sfasf;jk
>   Error. Please input an INTEGER: 1
>   You input 1

My code:

```
num=input("Please input an integer: ")
while type(num)!=int:
    num=input("Error. Please input an INTEGER: ")
print("You input",num)
```

Problem:
I want my code to keep looping until an **integer** is input. But, no matter what input I give, the code keeps rejecting it even if my input is an integer. How do I check whether my input is an integer or not? Inputs like string and floats must all be rejected according to my question.

Comment: You should use `type(num) is not int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` return value will always be of type `str`. You can check if it's an integer by trying to cast it to `int` and handling the exception, or better use `str.isdigit()` method:

```
num = input("Please input an integer: ")
while not num.isdigit():
    num = input("Error. Please input an INTEGER: ")
print("You input", int(num))
```

Also, if you want to support signs without messing with exceptions, you can use

```
num[0] in '+-' and num[1:].isdigit() or num.isdigit()
```

as the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `try : except`  block, that way you can handle all non-integers

**EDIT::** **Example**

```
num = False # This can be anything bool/float/etc.. as long it is not an int
while type(num) is not int:

    try:
    # Cast input as int
        num=int(input("Please input an integer: "))

    except ValueError:
    # Handles all non int's I catch the right exception
    # Leaving except empty is considered bad form
        print('Not correct format')

# Input passes converting so it must be an int
print("Num is correct type")
```

**Output**

```
>>> Please input an integer: 1.13 # Floats
>>> Not correct format 
>>> Please input an integer: 1.1 # Doubles
>>> Not correct format 
>>> Please input an integer: dfsdf # Strings
>>> Not correct format 
>>> Please input an integer: 9 # Int = Correct
>>> Num is correct type
```

Comment: The code you shared above works perfectly but does not solve my problem. My motive is to perform a validation check that will keep looping on until the correct   type of input is given. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: I edited my answer, it now has a loop to check for the correct input. I hope this will help solve your problem

Comment: Good! Now you can accept and answer so both you and the person who has the best answer can get some reputation. That is how SO works... Hopefully I was somewhat helpfull

Comment: Of course you were! From your answer, I learned about the try-except system. #respect